# LT6105 formula datasheet

Tags: current-measurement

I got a formula brain wreck, it should be me, but to avoid tomorrow a doctor visit, I will ask here first. It goes about the LT6105...

[image: LT6105]

It state that R*in1* = R*in2* = R*in*, but how is this true? What about the 0.2 resistor?

The result in the formula is V*out*, a voltage.... or not. What about the 1V/A?

The formula results.

A*v* = 4.99K/100 = 49,9Ω

R*in* = 100Ω

V*out* = ( 5V - 0V ) x 49,9Ω = 249,5(V??)

What wrong?

A big thank you to Big6
My new calc is now working correctly.

[image: Corrected calc]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

\$V_s^+\$ and \$V_s^-\$ in the circuit shown actually refer to the voltage **drop** across the 0.02 Ohm resistor -- not the voltage rails.

So if there is a 1A current through the 0.02 Ohm resistor, then the voltage drop across it, using Ohm's law would be (0.02 Ohm)*(1A) = 0.02V -- this is the same information you should get if you found \$V_s^+ - V_s^-\$. If you multiply the 0.02V drop by the gain of 49.9, you'd see **0.998V** at the output.

That is why the datasheet tells you that in that configuration, for every amp of current, you should see 1V increase (1V per Amp).

Comment: Thank you. Top. Will add a new image with the result.